# Sound delay on emulator in corona sdk

Tags: coronasdk

I'm currently creating a game with `corona sdk`. While creating game i faced issues in playing audio files. Issue was that, a tennis ball is dropped on ground and audio should be played. But what happen was the audio was delayed a second. On emulator the audio was synchronized but while i ported `apk` on my galaxy s2, android version 4.2.2 i faced a delay. Below is the code which i used to play audio.

I loaded audio file first as program executed:

```lua
local audio = audio.loadSound("hit ball.mp3")
```

Then somewhere in middle I used collision and on collision I played that audio file:

```lua
local function onCollisionSound()
      audio.play(audio)
end

ball:addEventListener("collision", onCollisionSound)
```

I also tried with media api but it also didnt worked.

Comment: did you try deploying in on higher end phones?

Answer (score 1):

This may be an issue with *OpenAL*. All `audio.*` methods are based on *OpenAL* which is not natively supported by the *Android NDK* (which supports *OpenSL ES*  instead). The solution to make it work is still a bit buggy and may introduced a delay with some Android versions/devices :

> *(Directly from the Corona SDK documentation of [`audio.play()`](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/audio/play.html))*
>
> NOTE: A known issue with Android causes sound to be delayed by 1 to 2
>   seconds when started.

You may try to use the *deprecated* `media.*` API instead which doesn't use *OpenAL*, this may resolve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used media api but now i feel a pause in game while it plays sound. Example, like if ball has to touch the ground, before it could touch the ground, it hangs and then touches the ground but audio is synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

Generally with Android 4.1 and later, the audio.* API calls shouldn't be lagging.  Google fixed the bug in the 4.1 release, but on older versions, it could still be a problem.  However, that doesn't mean the device maker hasn't done some things that hurt sound performance.  When exact timing is required, we do recommend using media.* API calls.

Also, please make sure your sound clip doesn't have any delays at the beginning.